# E: Unable to locate package pvrg-jpeg

Tags: 12.04, installation, package-management

I have installed `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS` and trying to installed the following package:

`sudo apt-get install pvrg-jpeg`

When I run the preceding command, I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pvrg-jpeg
```

How can I install the package?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**apt-cache policy pvrg-jpeg**

```
pvrg-jpeg:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.1+dfsg1-1
  Version table:
     1.2.1+dfsg1-1 0
        500 http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe amd64 Packages
```

Do you have universe repositories enabled ?

Check from Ubuntu Software Center > Edit > Software Sources > Ubuntu Software.

[image]